# document.querySelector is not working with "=" symbol inside the id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran into an error with the `document.querySelector()` function when using a specific type of id in an element. When the id is `canvas-=` then the querySelector fails with an error -> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#canvas-=' is not a valid selector.

But when I use `document.getElementById()`, it works. I can use `"[id='canvas-=']"` inside querySelector but why is it failing on `document.querySelector("#canvas-=")`?

1. `document.querySelector("#canvas-=")`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p id="canvas-=">This is a paragraph.</p>

<script>
const elem = document.querySelector("#canvas-=");
console.log(elem.innerHTML);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2. `document.getElementById("canvas-=")`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p id="canvas-=">This is a paragraph.</p>

<script>
const elem = document.getElementById("canvas-=");
console.log(elem.innerHTML);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But everything works fine if I remove `=` from the id. It doesn't work in any way you insert it. `==-`, `=-`, `-=` all of these give the error. So what is wrong with the `=` symbol in this and why does the second method works but the first doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is wrong with the `=` symbol in this
>
> ```
> document.querySelector("#canvas-=")
> ```

As mentioned in the [`querySelector` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> To match against an ID or selectors that do not follow standard CSS syntax (by using a colon or space inappropriately, for example), you must escape the character with a backslash ("`\`"). As the backslash is also an escape character in JavaScript, if you are entering a literal string, you must escape it *twice* (once for the JavaScript string, and another time for `querySelector()`):

**Working Demo:**

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#canvas-\\=");
console.log(elem.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p id="canvas-=">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

---

> why does the second method works but the first doesn't?

This happens because `getElementById()` does not use the same CSS3 selectors for querying the DOM and thus we can use special characters without any issues.

**Working Demo:**

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("canvas-=");
console.log(elem.innerHTML);

const elem2 = document.getElementById("canvas.foo");
console.log(elem2.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p id="canvas-=">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="canvas.foo">This is a 2nd paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector` method uses CSS3 selectors for querying the DOM.

That means

In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

clearly you have `=`. So without `=` it works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p id="canvas-">This is a paragraph.</p>

<script>
const elem = document.querySelector("#canvas-");
console.log(elem.innerHTML);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

More about it. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters
checkout topic 4.1.3